# Проблема сборки CMAKE Qt проекта в Linux в командной строке - собирается ELF shared

Tags: qt5, cmake

Детали проблемы:

1. Есть проект на Qt, сборка с помощью cmake. Собирается (в QtDesigner) и работает нормально и в Windows и в Linux (использую для теста Mint 21 x64 - Vanessa);
2. В Windows сборка из командной строки - нормально, собирается как и ожидалось;
3. При переносе в Linux zip-архивом, как и указано в п.1 QtCreator собирает проект нормально. Работает как из под отладчика так и автономно, запускаясь из "проводника" Linux;
4. Однако при сборке через командную строку Linux после сборки получается elf shared object, который имея флаг "исполняемый" запускается и работает ТОЛЬКО из командной строки, а "проводник" его не воспринимает как исполняемый.

Предполагаю, что при сборке в среде QtCreator что-то добавляется к cmake, однако по своей природной несообразительности никак не могу понять что, где, куда и когда. Покурив гугл выяснил, что "возможно gcc настроен не так а иначе" :).

Прошу помощи.

cmakelist.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
message("[INFO] CMake version: " ${CMAKE_VERSION})
#cmake.exe -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=C:/Qt/Qt5/5.14.2/mingw73_64 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/Qt/Qt5/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/Qt/Qt5/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/g++.exe
project(my_prj LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
#set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "MinGW MakeFiles")

if (WIN32)
    message("[INFO] Build Windows revision!")
    find_package(QT NAMES Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets svg REQUIRED)
    find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets svg REQUIRED)
    find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
endif(WIN32)

if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    message("[INFO] Build Linux revision!")
    message("[WARN] Qt SVG module removed from required package.")
    find_package(QT NAMES Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
    find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
    find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
endif()


message("[INFO] PostgreSQL VER: " ${PostgreSQL_VERSION_STRING})
message("[INFO] Include files PostgreSQL: " ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("[INFO] Lib files PostgreSQL: " ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        src/main.cpp
        src/winmain.cpp
        src/winmain.h
        src/winmain.ui
        src/resource/resources.qrc
        #-- общие модули расширения функционала
        src/common/classes/validators.h
 
 ... (очень много файлов)

)

include_directories(AFTER ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(AFTER ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(my_prj ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
else()
    add_executable(my_prj ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
endif()

if (WIN32)
    #сборка под Windows
    target_link_libraries(my_prj PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets libpq)
endif(WIN32)

if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    #сборка под Linux (различие в библиотеках)
    target_link_libraries(my_prj PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets pq)
endif()
```

Comment: Это проблемы исключительно файлового менеджера. Если есть необходимость запускать приложение из ФМ, лучше создать `.desktop` файл запуска.

Comment: повторюсь: сборка из QtDesigner решает проблему, но мне нужна сборка из командной строки, чтобы на машине клиента не ставить QtDesigner (в некоторых случаях установка среды разработки не приветствуется, увы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решилась добавлением

```
target_link_options (my_prj PUBLIC "-no-pie")
```

в последний if скрипта cmake